# Problema con UPDATE SQLSTATE[HY093]: linea 53

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estaba diseñando un CRUD, sin embargo al intentar configurar el boton de "Modificar" me aparece el error SQLSTATEHY093, por lo que he investigado es por las variables que no corresponden con el número de columnas

```
$txtID = (isset($_POST['id']))?$_POST['id']:"";
$txtCed = (isset($_POST['cedula'])) ? $_POST['cedula'] : "";
$txtNombre = (isset($_POST['nombre'])) ? $_POST['nombre'] : "";
$txtApellido = (isset($_POST['apellidos'])) ? $_POST['apellidos'] : "";
$txtCorreo = (isset($_POST['correo'])) ? $_POST['correo'] : "";
$txtTelefono = (isset($_POST['telefono'])) ? $_POST['telefono'] : "";
$txtEstado = (isset($_POST['estado'])) ? $_POST['estado'] : "";
$txtFoto = (isset($_POST['foto'])) ? $_POST['foto'] : "";
$accion = (isset($_POST['accion'])) ? $_POST['accion'] : "";

include("../system/global/conexion.php");

switch ($accion) {
    case "Agregar":

        $sentencia = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO alumnos(cedula,nombre,apellido,correo,telefono,estado,foto) VALUES (:cedula,:nombre,:apellido,:correo,:telefono,:estado,:foto)");


        $sentencia->bindParam(':cedula', $txtCed);
        $sentencia->bindParam(':nombre', $txtNombre);
        $sentencia->bindParam(':apellido', $txtApellido);
        $sentencia->bindParam(':correo', $txtCorreo);
        $sentencia->bindParam(':telefono', $txtTelefono);
        $sentencia->bindParam(':estado', $txtEstado);
        $sentencia->bindParam(':foto', $txtFoto);
        $sentencia->execute();

        echo "Agregar";
        break;

    case "Modificar": 

        $sentencia = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE alumnos SET
        cedula:celuda,
        nombre:nombre,
        apellido:apellido,
        correo:correo,
        telefono:telefono,
        estado:estado,
        foto:foto WHERE
        id=:id");

        $sentencia->bindParam(':cedula', $txtCed);
        $sentencia->bindParam(':nombre', $txtNombre);
        $sentencia->bindParam(':apellido', $txtApellido);
        $sentencia->bindParam(':correo', $txtCorreo);
        $sentencia->bindParam(':telefono', $txtTelefono);
        $sentencia->bindParam(':estado', $txtEstado);
        $sentencia->bindParam(':foto', $txtFoto);
        $sentencia->bindParam(':id',$txtID);
        $sentencia->execute(); //aqui esta el error, linea 53


        echo "Modificar";
        break;
```

El case de "Insertar" funciona, inserta los datos a la BD, el problema esta en el CASE "Modificar"
Agraceria mucho su apoyo, recien me adentro a PHP y me encantaria una retroalimentacion para aprender un poco más

Comment: Tu sentencia update esta mal escrita, esto `cedula:celuda` debería ser así `cedula = :celuda` y así por cada una de ellas, por otro lado revisa los nombres, seguro que es celuda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la parte del `UPDATE` te falta poner el signo de `=` en los `SET`.

Aparte de eso tienes un error tipográfico en el parámetro para la cédula, tienes escrito `:celuda` cuando por lo lógica, y en los `bindParam` se ve claramente que deberia ser `:cedula`

```
case "Modificar": 

    $sentencia = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE alumnos SET
    cedula=:cedula,
    nombre=:nombre,
    apellido=:apellido,
    correo=:correo,
    telefono=:telefono,
    estado=:estado,
    foto=:foto WHERE
    id=:id");

    $sentencia->bindParam(':cedula', $txtCed);
    $sentencia->bindParam(':nombre', $txtNombre);
    $sentencia->bindParam(':apellido', $txtApellido);
    $sentencia->bindParam(':correo', $txtCorreo);
    $sentencia->bindParam(':telefono', $txtTelefono);
    $sentencia->bindParam(':estado', $txtEstado);
    $sentencia->bindParam(':foto', $txtFoto);
    $sentencia->bindParam(':id',$txtID);
    $sentencia->execute(); //aqui esta el error, linea 53
```

Salvo otros errores, así debería funcionar.

Comment: He actualizado los campos, sin embargo al hacer la prueba, los datos no se actualizan

Comment: @Valentinsala había un error tipográfico también en el parámetro de `cedula`